# warranty time calculation of a product is not working using php

Tags: php, date

I am working a stuff with calculate warranty time of a product.A product have warranty 2 years 0 months.These  product is purchased  in these date '2015-07-24'.I want to calculate remaining warranty time of these product.I got the remaining warranty as '1 Years, 12 Months, 2 Days' using these below code.But actual warranty is '2 years' and remaining warranty is '1 Years, 12 Months, 2 Days'.Remaining warranty period is greater then actual warranty.Product is purchased before before 4 days ago,in the date '2015-07-24'.

Used these code

```
     $date3= '2015-07-24';
     $warranty_year= 2;
     $warranty_month    = 0;
     $newDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date3. " + {$warranty_year} year"));
     $newDate2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+{$warranty_month} months",  strtotime($newDate)));
     $current_date=date("Y-m-d");
     $date1Timestamp = strtotime($current_date);
     $date2Timestamp = strtotime($newDate2);
     $diff = $date2Timestamp - $date1Timestamp;
     $years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
     $months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
     $days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/   (60*60*24));
     printf("%d Years, %d Months, %d Days\n", $years, $months, $days);
```

Anybody help me?

Comment: PHP can do most of this work itself. Find the difference of two DateTime objects (using `DateTime::diff()` which gives you a `DateInterval` object, then format the `DateInterval` into words. There's an example in the PHP documentation - http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php#example-2486

Answer (score 3):

```
$warranty= date of purchase + 2years;
//dateof purchase write it as your variable from db

$date1=date_create( $warranty);// this is your warranty time after 2 years
$date2=date_create(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")) ;//this gives current time

$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
$noOfDays=$diff->format("%a days %H:%i:%s Hours");
echo $noOfDays;
```